# Return all values using LOOKUPVALUE, not just matches

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have two tables with related fields. I am trying to return the enrollment# from table A into a column in table B.

table A

```
Serial# Enrollment#
A       1
B       2
C       3
D       4
E       5
```

table B

```
Serial# Enrollment#
A       1
B       20
C       3
D       4
E       50
```

I  want this calculated column in table B

```
Serial# Enrollment# tableAEnrollment#
A       1           1
B       20          2
C       3           3
D       4           4
E       50          5
```

however this is what I am getting:

```
Serial# Enrollment# tableAEnrollment#
A       1           1
B       20          
C       3           3
D       4           4
E       50
```

my function is:

```
tableAEnrollemnt# = LOOKUPVALUE(A[Enrollment #], A[Serial #], B[Serial #])
```

Its only bringing back where enrollment numbers match. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I can't reproduce your results from your data and DAX (I'm not getting any blanks).

Comment: Interesting, so do you have any idea what could be wrong (Possibly a connection in the model?)

Comment: Hard to say. Can you upload a pbix?